# GIT: How to undo merge?

Tags: git, git-merge

I've done merge `some-branch` into `master`, but gets confilcts. How to undo this ?

```
git checkout master
git merge some-branch
...
CONFLICTS :(
```

Comment: did you try git reset --hard ?

Comment: I checked this. Works! how can I thank You?

Comment: careful with `reset --hard`.. you can cut yourself with that in other cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have conflicts, your merge will not be committed yet so you can use `git reset --hard HEAD` to remove the merge.

Comment: do not encourage the use of `git reset --hard`

Answer (score 15):

```
git merge --abort
```

is a recently added option. It does what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

With modern git, you can, as suggested in previous answer:

```
git merge --abort
```

Older syntax:

```
git reset --merge
```

Old-school, also suggested in previous answer:

```
git reset --hard
```

But actually, it is worth noticing that `git merge --abort` is only equivalent to `git reset --merge` given that `MERGE_HEAD` is present. This can be read in the git help for merge command.

```
git merge --abort is equivalent to git reset --merge when MERGE_HEAD is present.
```

After a failed merge, when there is no `MERGE_HEAD`, the failed merge can be undone with `git reset --merge` but not necessarily with `git merge --abort`, **so they are not only old and new syntax for the same thing**.

Personally I find `git reset --merge` more useful in everyday work so this is the method i use all the time.